# FreeIPA LDAPSearch for group membership

Tags: openldap, ldap-query, freeipa, rocky-os

Freeipa 4.9.10

Rocky 8.7

LdapSearch 2.4.46

I am trying to get the list of user's uid that belongs to specific group. Then ultimately get the email address of those users.

`ldapsearch -x -H ldap://10.0.0.33 -W -D "cn=Directory Manager" '(memberOf=cn=admins,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com)'`

````
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: (memberOf=cn=admins,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success```
````

Answer (score 0):

Group membership information requires authenticated bind to see. You are using anonymous bind, hence not seeing those attributes.

Comment: I already tried using authentication. with the following command:
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://IP -W -D "uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com" '(memberOf=cn=admins,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com)'
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

Comment: this means you entered incorrect password. This `ldapsearch` line works for me against my FreeIPA setup.